# Compound Independent Probability of Random Events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, weighted-regression

I'm trying to write a solver for random data and I hit a bit of a statistics brick wall, I wonder if someone might be able to shed some light.

If we consider a bag of 10 balls, each one is unique and then say we select 3 of them and we do this 6 times. So if we assume this to be a totally independent event, then each time you have a 1/10 chance of getting any of the balls.

Once the balls are uniquely identifiable does it not change the problem of probabilities slightly? Here are 6 random draws from the bag:

[image: Random selections]

My proposal is that if we are considering an event as part of a series of events, then it's no longer equal probability of all the outcomes... for example:

On the 1st run you have the same probability of picking any number (0.1)

On the 2nd run you have the same probability of picking any number (0.1) however you have a 70% chance of drawing a number that hasn't been drawn in the previous run.

On the 3rd run, 10% chance of picking a number, but also 70% chance of not picking a number from run2, and a 70% chance of not picking a number from run1

I am wondering what are some of the ways people would tackle writing this notation, ultimately I want to use it as part of a c# definition for analysing seemingly random data and to try predict trends or replicate certain datasets computationally

I mean I might be wrong entirely and would love to be corrected, but I am wondering if before we get to the law of large numbers, we can actually start extracting trends from random or seemingly random data?

Thanks a lot,

Sash

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You say that there is a 10% probability of picking each number, and a 70% probability of picking one of the seven numbers that wasn't picked last time (70%=7*10%).

Comment: I felt like I was missing an operation as the probabilities no longer add up to 1 - so the blanks would be 0.07 and the hatches would be 0.03 - so the sum of the probabilities would be 0.58 - did I not lose 0.42 somewhere?

Comment: Based on your comment, it appears you are treating the events $A$: *event that a ball not selected in the previous run is selected* and $B$: *event that ball i is selected* as independent events. This is not the case. If we know a ball was not selected in the previous run, then that limits us to seven balls. The conditional probability that any single one of those balls is selected is not 1/10, but 1/7. The total probability that one will select, let's say, ball 1 in the second round, is not 7/10 * 1/10, but 7/10 * 1/7.  Does this address your confusion?

Comment: Wait do you mean if the balls are removed it's 1/7? - because the system is reset each time to 10 balls again, my issue is the fact that they are independent events and though it's ultimately a fair system - I'm trying  to record over time which values are triggered and with what frequency to be able to store a "weighted" probability(which is essentially a function of the history of the previous selections)